# Can Java glob several JAR files in a CLASSPATH directory with an asterisk (*)?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'd like to reference several JARs at once in my CLASSPATH. Can I use an asterisk for this?

Comment: Yes you can use. Can you give some more detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
java -cp "lib/*" MainClass
```

Note that quotes are mandatory, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) for additional details.

Comment: unfreaking believable, never knew this!

Comment: Be aware that this isn't quite "globbing" in the Unix sense; the JVM specifically looks for the character `*` (which you need to protect from the shell, e.g. by using the double-quotes above) and grabs all the jars in the directory when it sees it.

Comment: @chrylis the comment should really be part of the answer. Mind adding it?